# Placing live Stack Exchange reputation in a document

Tags: luatex

I want to be able to place my *current* reputation into a document, such that, when I rebuild the document, the displayed reputation is updated.

For example, I might write

```
My current reputation on {\tt tex.se} is \texrep.
```

and get (assuming `\texrep` is defined)

[image: My current reputation on tex.se is 43.]

To do this, I expect `\texrep` would be defined as `\directlua{get_rep('tex')}`, where `get_rep` is a Lua function defined in an external Lua script (say, `fetch.lua`).

---

Note:  I have given an answer to my own question, for two reasons:

1. to see if my method can be improved; and
2. to share this 'discovery' with others.

---

**Update:** my answer is rather long, and has the unfortunate side effect of blocking everything else on the page! **Make sure to check the other answers** below mine, as they have improved on my method.

Comment: I don't think this is a LaTeX question, though it is interesting.

Comment: @Johannes_B; Since it's about the capabilities of (Lua)TeX, and pushing the boundaries of a TeX document, I feel it is.

Comment: Just FYI, the old `{\tt foo}`, `{\bf foo}`, `{\it foo}` etc. commands are 20+ years deprecated. `{\ttfamily foo}`, `{\bfseries foo}`, `{\itshape foo}` or `\texttt{foo}`, `\textbf{foo}`, `\textit{foo}` are strictly encouraged. Self-answering is also explicitly acceptable on Stackexchange, although admittedly some people (and some stacks) don't like it, but you certainly don't have to justify yourself, I thought this was cool :)

Comment: @Au101; I used `\tt` because I was using Plain (Lua)TeX, to make the question as general as possible (so it would also apply to ConTeXt etc.): but you are right!

Comment: Oh, fair enough, I didn't realise you were using plain :)

Answer (score 26):

If you just want the code, and not the explanation, look [here](https://gist.github.com/daantjie/0421d3ad4c0f21ee35e1fc389d1090d9).

---

The trick is to use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) to download the information on a user. For example, to get my own user information (regarding tex.se), I would go to `http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?inname=digitalis_&site=tex`. For a different user, or a different site, you would change the respective fields.

Let's put this into a function, `curl_user`:

```
curl_user = function (user, site)
   os.execute('mkdir -p cache')
   print('\nGetting ' .. user .. ' from ' .. site .. '...\n')
   os.execute('curl "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?inname='
      .. user .. '&site=' .. site
      .. '" > ' .. cache_name(user, site) .. '.gz')
   os.execute('gunzip -f ' .. cache_name(user, site) .. '.gz')
end
```

where `cache_name` is

```
cache_name = function (user, site)
   return ('cache/' .. user .. '_' .. site)
end
```

Because the API limits you to 300 requests per day, it's a bad idea to re-download the user information every time you need it. The solution is to cache the data, in two ways:

1. **Per document build.** E.g., the first time I write `\texrep`, it downloads the data and stores it in a variable, so that subsequent occurrences of `\texrep` use the value stored in memory.
2. **On the hard drive.** E.g., calling `\texrep` the first time downloads the data and saves it to a file on the hard drive (say, `digitalis_tex`), and subsequent document builds read the value from this file.

`curl_user` already deals with (1) by saving the data in the `cache/` directory, under I file with the name `<user>_<site>`.

A consequence of (2) is that there will need to be a variable which determines whether Lua should re-download or not. We will set it to `true` for now, as well as creating the table which caches data 'per build'.

```
UPDATING = true
cache = {}
```

A function is needed to manage this cache:

```
get_user = function (user, userid, site)
   if cache[user] == nil then
      cache[user] = {}
   end

   if cache[user][site] == nil then
      cache[user][site] = {}
      cache[user][site]['_raw'] = extract_user(user, userid, site)
   end

   return cache[user][site]['_raw']
end
```

where `extract_user` is defined as

```
extract_user = function (user, userid, site)
   if UPDATING then
      curl_user(user, site)
   end

   io.input(cache_name(user, site))
   raw = io.read('*all')
   me = string.match(raw, userid .. '.*')
   return me
end
```

`extract_user` chooses whether to update the saved cache on the hard drive, and uses some pattern matching magic to filter out users which are not wanted. This is needed because of how the API request works: it actually gives you the data of all users whose names have a particular string in them. To differentiate from other users, you need the user's ID (which you can find by looking at the url when you visit your profile on http://stackexchange.com).

You can see how the cache starts to evolve as a kind of tree:

```
cache
 └── digitalis
      ├── tex
      │    └── _raw
      └── stackoverflow
           └── _raw
```

All that is now desired is a general function to acquire a value, given:

- a field,
- a user,
- a site.

Here is such a function:

```
get_field = function (field, user, userid, site)
   if not (cache[user]
          and cache[user][site]
          and cache[user][site][field]) then
      me = get_user(user, userid, site)
      pure = string.match(me, '"' .. field .. '":[^,}]+')
      cache[user][site][field] = string.match(pure, '[^:]+$')
   end
   return cache[user][site][field]
end
```

It initialises the cache if parts of it are not defined, and returns the desired value.

---

To get the effect in the question, one may write

```
get_rep = function (site)
   return get_field('reputation', USER, USERID, site)
end
```

where `USER` and `USERID` are set to some user's username and user ID.

```
USER = 'digitalis'
USERID = 5477562
```

The entire .tex file would then be

```
\directlua{dofile('fetch.lua')}
\def\texrep{\directlua{get_rep('tex')}}
My current reputation on {\tt tex.se} is \texrep.
\bye
```

Note that the functions defined here are general enough to be used for more than just getting the reputation of the user: e.g.,

- the number of badges,
- the change in reputation in the last year/quarter/month,
- the url to the profile image,
- etc.

are all possible.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a ConTeXt implementation of the command. I use a slightly [different API call](https://stackapps.com/questions/2704/stack-overflow-reputation-api) to get the reputation.

ConTeXt has an inbuilt mechanism to download remote content. This content is cached in a directory inside `texmf-cache`. So, the idea is to simply download the content, unzip it, convert from json to lua table, and access the value of the key `reputation`. LuaTeX comes with the `gzip` library, and ConTeXt has a parser for JSON; so there is no need to use an external program at all.

```
\usemodule[json]
\startluacode
  local get_user_reputation = function(user)
    local url           = string.format("http://api.stackexchange.com//2.2/users/%s?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=tex", user)
    local specification = resolvers.splitmethod(url)
    local filename      = resolvers.finders['http'](specification) or ""

    local gz = gzip.open(filename, "rb")
    local str = ""
    if gz then
        str = gz:read("*all")
        gz:close()
    end
    local js  = utilities.json.tolua(str)
    local rep = js["items"][1]["reputation"] or "0"
    context(rep)
  end

  interfaces.definecommand {
      name = "getrep",
      arguments = {
        { "option", "number" }, 
      },
      macro = get_user_reputation,
  }

\stopluacode

\starttext

My current reputation on \type{tex.se} is \getrep[323].

\stoptext
```

Since the json object returns a lot of information, so you can extract other keys as well. For example, in my case, this is the information that I get:

```
t={
 ["has_more"]=false,
 ["items"]={
  {
   ["accept_rate"]=88,
   ["account_id"]=65687,
   ["badge_counts"]={
    ["bronze"]=188,
    ["gold"]=2,
    ["silver"]=82,
   },
   ["creation_date"]=1280861336,
   ["display_name"]="Aditya",
   ["is_employee"]=false,
   ["last_access_date"]=1466999559,
   ["last_modified_date"]=1464661963,
   ["link"]="http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya",
   ["profile_image"]="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9734cf7ba55eda3a1707cd61a452bdce?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
   ["reputation"]=44190,
   ["reputation_change_day"]=10,
   ["reputation_change_month"]=1060,
   ["reputation_change_quarter"]=1612,
   ["reputation_change_week"]=50,
   ["reputation_change_year"]=3347,
   ["user_id"]=323,
   ["user_type"]="registered",
   ["website_url"]="http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/",
  },
 },
 ["quota_max"]=300,
 ["quota_remaining"]=285,
}
```

By default, ConTeXt will fetch the data again if the cache is older than 1 day. If you want to update more quickly (note that there is rate throttling in stackexchange API), add:

```
\enabledirectives[schemes.threshold=1200]
```

which will update the cache after 1200 sec (i.e., 20 min).

Comment: The thing that's very interesting to me about this one is how ConTeXt will re-fetch after a certain amount of time has elapsed (thus eliminating the need for an `UPDATING` variable which is set manually).

Comment: The built-in JSON parser is also much more clean than my regexp solution.

Comment: @digitalis_: LPEG based parsers are usually much cleaner than those based on regex.